# Get the access to the folder file system/root

Tags: permissions, filesystem, root

I am using a live version of Xubuntu on USB for a extraordinary maintenance of my PC.
I have to copy a single file inside the folder file system/root.

Currently I can browse the complete folder file system, but the root folder in it is marked with a cross and it prompts `permission denied` while trying to open it or if I try to copy file inside it.

Comment: have you tried sudo ?

Answer (score 1):

use terminal and
use this comand to copy

```
sudo cp -R file-need-to-copy-path  path-of-folder-where-you-want-to-paste
```

or you can change the permission of that folder by using

```
sudo chmod 777 path-of-folder
```

Answer (score 0):

That means you don't have viewing permission for that folder. You could solve that simply by allowing your user viewing rights for that folder with this command:

`sudo chmod 755 /path/to/folder`

or you can change folder owner from root to yourself with

`sudo chown your_user_name:users /path/to/folder`

Don't forget to substitute your_user_name with actually username.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this is **not recommended**, but if you are just using a live system and are willing to risk to break the system you can do:

Alt+F2 -> `gksudo nautilus`

But be careful: You can ruin your system very easily this way (e.g. by deleting/modifying crucial files by accident), so do not use it unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You just copy the folder that you want the permission of. Then type this command.

> sudo chmod 755 /path/to/folder

You don't need to copy /path/to/folder. You need to replace that by pasting the copied folder.